# Use NOAA Hurricane Tracker KML and Overlay it in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis, kml

I'm trying to create a hurricane trajectory/prediction overlay on leaflet, but its not working.  I'm trying to use the below KML file, but no error message or images get displayed.  I would like a forecast hurricane overlay to display on the map, but no luck.  Let me know if anyone has this issue or can solve this problem.

KML file: https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/kml/nhc_active.kml

```
console.log("loading hurricanes...");
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-style
    style: function (feature) {
        return { color: '#f00' };
    }
});
var runLayer = omnivore.kml('nhc_active.kml', null, customLayer)
            .on('ready', function () {
                runLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.description);
                });
            })
            .on('error', function (e) {
                console.log("Error loading KML: ", e);
            })

console.log("hurricane loaded");
```

Comment: Did you copy the KML file to your server?

Comment: If not, I get a CORs error.

Comment: Should the title be: "Use NOAA Hurricane Tracker KML and Overlay it in Leaflet"? (with a "t" rather than a "y")